# pandas: iterate over dataframe, do SQL query for each row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and a 5 million row local Postgres database. In each row of the dataframe, I want to add a column that is the result of a query against the Postgres database.

This is what I have right now:

```
for index, row in df_tf.iterrows():
    row = dict(row)
    id = row['National ID']
    q = 'select name from companies where company_number=%s'
    cursor.execute(q, [company_number])
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    if len(results):
        row['name'] = result[0][0]
        writer.writerow(row)
    else:
        row['name'] = ''
        writer.writerow(row)
```

So I'm iterating over the rows and writing the results to a local CSV.

Is there a way I could do this more neatly, and keep the results in a local dataframe?

I know I could load the Postgres data into pandas and join directly, but it's rather large and slow, so I would prefer to use a Postgres query.

Comment: Since you only ever consume the first result a `fetchone()` would likely help tidy things up and be faster

Comment: What is the average size of the `df`?

Comment: @P.Naoum it's not very big, about 80,000 rows. The Postgres data is bigger, about 5 milllion rows / 2.5GB. I could load it into memory but would prefer not to (and am also interested in the answer for datasets that really are too big for memory!).

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it with [sqlalchemy declarative_base](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html?highlight=declarative_base#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base).

Rough code:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import String, Integer # noqa
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(#some stuff)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))()

class Companies(base):
    __tablename__ = 'companies'
    name = Column(String)
    company_number = Column(Integer)
    ...
    #other stuff

 @classmethod
 def get_by_company_number(cls, company_number):
    query = session.query(cls).filter(cls.company_number == company_number)
    if query.count() == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        return query.first().name
 
 df_tf['name'] = df_tf['National ID'].apply(Companies.get_by_company_number)
 df_tf.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think my first look would be something like (untested):

```
import pandas
import psycopg2
import csv
import contextlib

def get_company_name(cursor, company_number):
    query = 'SELECT name FROM companies WHERE company_number=%s;'
    cursor.execute(query, [company_number])
    results = cursor.fetchone()
    return results[0] if results else ''

df_tf = pandas.DataFrame("...")
with contextlib.ExitStack() as ctx:
    connection = ctx.enter_context(psycopg2.connect("..."))
    cursor = ctx.enter_context(connection.cursor())
    file_out = ctx.enter_context(open("results.csv", "w"))
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file_out, fieldnames=["National ID", "Name"])
    writer.writeheader()
    for _, row in df_tf.iterrows():
        row = dict(row)
        row['Name'] = get_company_name(cursor, row['National ID'])
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Depending on the data in the dataframe, it might be worth it to cache results from `get_company_name()`. I imagine there are better answer, but this is what I would try out of the gate.